# Are all files in a collection A, accounted for in a differently structured collection B?

Tags: file, bash, compare

If I have two collections of files: A and B (say, two collections of photos). There is an overlap between the two collections (some to all photos in collection A also exist in collection B - perhaps with a different filename) but in a (potentially) different directory structure. Furthermore, files in collection A might appear multiple times in various places in collection B and the other way around (although the filenames may differ).

How would I know for sure, that I can can safely delete collection A (i.e. that all files in collection A exist at least once somewhere in collection B)?

Again, it's about file content, not filenames.

- diff and derivatives don't help me since they complain about the differing file structure between collections A and B.
- fdupes (http://linux.die.net/man/1/fdupes) (which compares file sizes and MD5 signatures, and then performs a byte-by-byte check for verification) is a handy tool for checking doubles but has the nasty habit of being unpredictable about removing from which collection it removes the double file. The "manual" option is far to time consuming.

fdupes also just seems to be the wrong tool. I simply need to know if all files in collection A are accounted for in collection B.

Comment: Did you not find anything to your liking in the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdupes page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First making from both collections md5sum files

```
    find CollectionA  -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum -b > CollectionA.MD5SUM
    find CollectionB  -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum -b > CollectionB.MD5SUM
```

After that you would find all missed files in CollectionB

```
   (while read MD5SUM FILENAME; do grep -qis $MD5SUM CollectionB.MD5SUM || echo $FILENAME does not exist in CollectionB; done)<CollectionA.MD5SUM
```

More conveniant

```
   (while read MD5SUM FILENAME; do grep -qis $MD5SUM CollectionB.MD5SUM || echo ${FILENAME#\*} does not exist in CollectionB; done)<CollectionA.MD5SUM
```

to strip the * from the beginning of the filename.

You must be aware, that this solution is pretty slow.

Comment: Perhaps cutting `CollectionB` in, say, half and running two threads (given that you at least two cores) would speed this solution up a bit. Is it even possible to 'assign a tread to a processor' in Bash?

Comment: If you want to split this, you would split `CollectionA', to get the right result, because we match every entry in A to B. i Havn't tried to assigning a script or the correspondijg process to a core.

Comment: **GNU parallel** to the rescue: 

`parallel --eta -a CollectionA.MD5SUM --colsep '\s' "grep -iq {1} CollectionB.MD5SUM || echo {2}"`